# Relative path not working over iis 7.5 however it works in debug mode vs 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc, relative-path

To brief our problem, i am using MVC Application by default created by VS, only thing i have added image folder have one logo image.

I am using this image in site master as a logo path i am using to access it ../../Images/logo.png.

This logo image gets loaded in debug mode vs 2010 but when i publish it in local host iis 7.5 it does not get loaded. while clicking on error it shows different path.

Although above things works at my shared server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i have googled alot and find some tips over some page, here is the remedy 
I used src='<%ResolveUrl("../../Images/logo.png")%>' and it is working fine